# Proving that a function with two variables is injective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

I need to prove that the function $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by $f(x,y)=2^x\cdot 3^y$ is injective.

Is there an easier method than to use logarithms?

The function certainly looks injective, but I don't know how to show it.

How would I start in this case?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ supposed to be?

Comment: @EricWofsey The domain is $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ and the codomain is $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Can you use the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Answer (score 5):

Well assume you have $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$ with $f(x_{1},y_{1}) = f(x_{2},y_{2})$. W.l.o.g. assume $x_{1}\ge x_{2}$, then:

$$2^{x_{1}}3^{y_{1}} = 2^{x_{2}}3^{y_{2}} \iff 2^{x_{1}-x_{2}}3^{y_{1}} = 3^{y_{2}}.$$

If $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$ then $2$ divides $3^{y_{2}}$ which is absurd. Hence $x_{1}=x_{2}$ and therefore $y_{1}=y_{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your domain is $ \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $, you can simply argue that you can find $x, y$ from $f(x, y)$ by looking at it's prime factorization.

Comment: OP stated it in a comment in his original post